# sorting multiple lists based on a single list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm printing a few lists but the values are not sorted.

```
for f, h, u, ue, b, be, p, pe, m, me in zip(filename, human_rating, rating_unigram, percentage_error_unigram, rating_bigram, percentage_error_bigram, rating_pos, percentage_error_pos, machine_rating, percentage_error_machine_rating):
        print "{:>6s}{:>5.1f}{:>7.2f}{:>8.2f} {:>7.2f} {:>7.2f}  {:>7.2f} {:>8.2f}  {:>7.2f} {:>8.2f}".format(f,h,u,ue,b,be,p,pe,m,me)
```

What's the best way to sort all of these lists based on the values in 'filename'?

So if:

```
filename = ['f3','f1','f2']
human_rating = ['1','2','3']
etc.
```

Then sorting would return:

```
filename = ['f1','f2','f3']
human_rating = ['2','3','1']
etc.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would zip then sort:

```
zipped = zip(filename, human_rating, …)
zipped.sort()
for row in zipped:
     print "{:>6s}{:>5.1f}…".format(*row)
```

If you really want to get the individual lists back, I would sort them as above, then unzip them:

```
filename, human_rating, … = zip(*zipped)
```

Comment: Python 3 note: zip returns an iterator in Python 3, use list to see its content,

`zipped = list(zip(filename, human_rating, …))`

Comment: @David Wolever very nice solution.

Comment: In case you're getting ``'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'`` error, use ``sorted(zipped)`` as @jochen-ritzel mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 11):

How about this: `zip` into a list of tuples, sort the list of tuples, then "unzip"?

```
l = zip(filename, human_rating, ...)
l.sort()
# 'unzip'
filename, human_rating ... = zip(*l)
```

Or in one line:

```
filename, human_rating, ... = zip(*sorted(zip(filename, human_rating, ...)))
```

Sample run:

```
foo = ["c", "b", "a"]
bar = [1, 2, 3]
foo, bar = zip(*sorted(zip(foo, bar)))
print foo, "|", bar # prints ('a', 'b', 'c') | (3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Nice and compact solution! the problem is that it returns tuples not lists.

Comment: @ParisaKhateri Combine it with `map` if you need lists: `l1, l2, l3, ... = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2, l3, ...))))`

Answer (score 2):

`zip` returns a list of tuples which you can sort by their first value. So:

```
for ... in sorted(zip( ... )):
    print " ... "
```