# Sorting list of lists based on a given string in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
list_of_lists = [
   ('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
   ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
   ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3'),
   ('test_ss', 'Test 4')
]
```

I need to sort this list of lists by the first item in each list based on a given variable string.

As an example, I want to sort by 'test_ss' to the resulting list of lists would be:

```
sorted_list_of_lists = [
   ('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
   ('test_ss', 'Test 4'),
   ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
   ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3'),
]
```

I've tried a number of examples off SO and others ([Sorting a list of lists based on a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776134/sorting-a-list-of-lists-based-on-a-list-of-strings), [Sorting lists based on a particular element - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898748/sorting-lists-based-on-a-particular-element-python), [sorting multiple lists based on a single list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601961/sorting-multiple-lists-based-on-a-single-list-in-python), etc) but haven't found the right approach (or I've just not been following those examples correctly.

Any pointers?

Comment: @arman - thanks for the edit...I thought I did it right but apparently I did not :)

Comment: What if the first string of two elements is equal, is the sorting arbitrary, or do you want to introduce a tie breaker?

Comment: apparently you want some kind of a natural sort, since `test_2_ss` should come before `test_ss` (since `2`'s code is lower than `s`'). Do `sorted(list_of_lists)` and see it for yourself

Comment: What does it mean "sort by 'test_ss'", sort by the first position?

Comment: Eric, please answer @karakfa's comment

Comment: @EricD.Brown, Do you want `test_ss` behave like `test_1_ss` while sorting?

Comment: @karakfa - I want to sort by the values in the first position.

Comment: in what order?  Since digits come before alphabetical chars in ascii table.  My guess is sort by eliminating prefix and suffix

Comment: the final order should be the same order as the input list except for the given 'sort term' (in this case 'test_ss'). The final order is given in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple key function like this:

```
In [59]: def compare(element):
   ....:     return element[0] == 'test_ss' or 99999
   ....: 

In [60]: sorted(list_of_lists, key=compare)
Out[60]: 
[('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
 ('test_ss', 'Test 4'),
 ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
 ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3')]
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need in a way that is perfect for my implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to partition, just return `False` if the string matches:

```
>>> sorted(list_of_lists, key=lambda value: value[0] != 'test_ss')
[('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
 ('test_ss', 'Test 4'),
 ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
 ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3')]
```

Comment: that may turn out to be a good wild guess on what the OP wants

Comment: @Pynchia wild guess!

Comment: OK, maybe I am the only one who hasn't understood the question. I thought he wanted to sort by a specific position of the tuple, but it's unclear (see above my comment to the question)

Comment: perhaps distance to `test_ss` in some semantic way or perhaps edit distance.

Comment: @Pynchia - I want to sort by a text value in the list. The position of that doesn't matter...just the value of the string in the first 'column' (wrong nomenclature but you get my point I think).

Comment: @PeterWood - I think this is actually it.  Let me pay around with it.

Comment: @PeterWood upvoted. I think you'd nailed it from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

this will do

```
tuples = [
   ('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
   ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
   ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3'),
   ('test_ss', 'Test 4')
]

sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: x[0].replace('test_ss','test_ _ss'))

[('test_ss', 'Test 1'),
 ('test_ss', 'Test 4'),
 ('test_2_ss', 'Test 2'),
 ('test_3_ss', 'Test 3')]
```

you want to treat 'test_ss' semantically as the smallest element in sorting order but it's not in textual representation.  `key.replace(..)` handles it.